# Looping through a 3x3 cube

Tags: java, loops, 3d, cube

I am coding a mod for minecraft, and was confronted by a confusing math problem.
I want to find the ID of all blocks around a center block.
To do this I wanted to loop through a 3x3 square of blocks and return which ones are the blocks I want.

The parameters I have to work with are the X, Y and Z coords.
I'm guessing the best bet would be to use 3 for loops, one for each axis, right?

Comment: yes right. 3x3 not a big deal if you use Three loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
          //do something
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I was overthinking it. I don't know why I didn't think of that.



for (int x = xBlock; x < xBlock + 3; x++) {
   for (int y = yBlock; y < yBlock + 3; y++) {
    for (int z = zBlock; z < zBlock + 3; z++) {
     world.destroyBlock(x, y, z, true);
    }
   }
  }



I just need it to check from the middle block. At the moment its checking from the block at '0'.
I couldn't get the grey code blocks working, sorry... New to this place.